# Что влияет на скорость работы эмулятора в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Что влияет на скорость работы эмулятора в Android Studio? Правильно ли я понимаю, что в большей степени играет роль количество оперативной памяти? Насколько заметна разница в запусках эмулятора при 8/12 гб оперативной памяти и 16 гб? Заранее благодарна за любой ответ

Comment: влияет все железо связанное с виртуализацией:  ресурсам ОЗУ и ЦП

Comment: Оперативная память никак не влияет, главное, что бы её хватало. Если её не будет хватать любое приложение будет тормозить.